# Laravel raw query: total with select inside count

Tags: sql, laravel

I'm building a SQL query (Postgres is it matters), that will return me the list of articles with all the fields and with total number of references.

```
$a = Articles::select(DB::raw('
            *,
            count(
                select * from "references"
                where exists (select * from "users" where "users"."reference_id" = "references"."id"
                and "article_id" = ?????
            ) as total'
    ))->where('created_at', '<', $date)->get();
```

I simplified it a little bit; there more 'exists' conditions inside the count(); there is also more ->where() rules that are dynamic and hard to rewrite in raw SQL. My main misunderstanding is how to put the corresponding article_id instead of ?????. Could someone give me a hint.

Answer (score 2):

Try this its about binding parameter to Raw query.
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-bind-parameters-to-a-raw-query?page=1

Comment: Please add some code or content to your answer and not just a link to another page :)

Answer (score 2):

You may pass in the parameters to be bound to the raw select using a PHP array:

```
$a = Articles::select(DB::raw('
         *,
         count(
             select * from references r
             where exists (select 1 from users u
                           where u.reference_id = r.id and article_id = ?)
        ) as total', ['some id here']))
    ->where('created_at', '<', $date)
    ->get();
```

There may be a better way to write your query in Postgres.  If you can add some sample data, maybe more can be said about that.

Comment: but this 'some id here' should come from current article_id for which I'm running this count and which I'm getting via Articles::select (*); so I don't understand how to call it from within the query

Comment: Now you've lost me.  I have answered your exact question, regarding how to bind a parameter to a raw Laravel select.  If your query has some other problem, then show sample data which explains your query.

Comment: So, if I put 'id' in the brackets, it will use the current article id, correct?

Comment: Yes, something like `[$some_article_id]` should work.  If you want to use a _column_ available in the actual query, then you _don't_ need to bind a parameter; just use regular SQL.  Again, if you need help with the query, then show some data.

Comment: But article_id is dynamically selected. I don't have $some_article_id up front.
`Articles::select(DB::raw('` gives me the list of articles, each having unique id. And count() should contain this id - different for each row.

Comment: Your query logic has a problem (different question than what you asked originally, by the way).  Edit your question, and provide sample data for all tables, and the expected output.  I won't comment here further.